# Perl function knowing receiver type

Tags: perl, function

I have a text file, and a function to retrieve from that text file:

```
@thefile = read_file( 'somepathfile' );
```

I would like to have a different implementation of the `read_file` function depending on which type is receiving the information.

So if I write:

```
%thefile = read_file( 'somepathfile' );
```

then a different function will be executed.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [`Want`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Want/) or [`Contextual::Return`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Contextual-Return/) CPAN modules.

Below is a simple example using [`Want`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Want/):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Want;

sub read_file {
    my $filepath = shift;
    my @file_contents = get_file_contents($filepath);

    return @file_contents if want('LIST');

    return { 
        filepath => $filepath, 
        content  => \@file_contents, 
        lines    => scalar @file_contents 
    } if want('HASH');

    die "Nothing for that context!";
}

my @list = read_file('foo');
my %hash = %{ read_file('foo') };
```

NB. The hash dereference is needed to force the return context.

/I3az/

Comment: is there any way of doing this without the %{} around hash calls?

Comment: this is a solution, a suboptimal solution but nevertheless, a solution.

Comment: Not really.  Perl only understands scalar, list or void contexts so heaven knows what hoops the Want module has to goes through.  Personally I prefer to be more implicit with my contexts and would go for something like Sinan's answer or perhaps an object.  for eg. MyFile->read('file.txt')->as_list (see gist: http://gist.github.com/487366)

Comment: to install in shell:
sudo apt-get install libwant-perl

Comment: `Personally I prefer to be more implicit with my contexts` - oops that should be "explicit" :)

Answer (score 12):

While [draegtun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308149/perl-function-knowing-receiver-type/3308591#3308591) illustrates a nice technique, I am going to recommend clarity. For example:

```
@thefile = read_file_lines( 'somepathfile' );

%thefile = read_file_pairs( 'somepathfile' );
```

Comment: To put it more directly: Don't synthesize a new "hash" context on top of the scalar/list/void contexts that Perl already has. It's un-perlish and will confuse people.

Comment: yes but the original purpose was to use just a single function to read from the file. the function would then find out what is receiving and act accordingly.